# Is it possible to use local SQLite3 file with FileSystemAPI and WebAssembly in a web app?

Tags: webassembly, native-file-system-api-js

Considering that:

- Browser's File System API enables web apps to write on local files, without subsequent asks for permissions.
- WebAssembly can run a native SQLite3 client.

It's possible to create a web app that asks for a local SQLite3 file and give WebAssembly client access to it? For example, to create a full-static "SQLite3 administrator" web app.

I want to start an open source project like this (React+Go+WebAssembly), as a proof of concept, but I don't know if these APIs support that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use case is exactly what the [Storage Foundation API](https://github.com/fivedots/storage-foundation-api-explainer) proposal was created for. You can test this API in Chrome by setting the `#experimental-web-platform-features` flag. If you run into any trouble, please file a new Issue in the GitHub repository.